# C# dll in powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, dll

I want to do something to C # code executed from a script powershell. The question arose as to add a third-party library in the project?I am doing so

```
$path = @("C:\Users\name\Desktop\ch\packages\System.Data.SQLite.1.0.97.0")
$cSharp = @"my C# code"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $cSharp -ReferencedAssemblies $path
```

But when i start having problems running the script error:

> This assembly name or codebase invalid. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131047).

I want to add the concrete version of the library System.Data.SQLite.dll

Comment: wouldn't be easier if you define such code in a .NET assembly and then you call it from Powershell?

Comment: First, you can use Assembly.Load() method in your script.
Second, you didn't set extension in your file:
"C:\Users\name\Desktop\ch\packages\System.Data.SQLite.1.0.97.0". Try to add ".dll"
"C:\Users\name\Desktop\ch\packages\System.Data.SQLite.1.0.97.0.dll"

Comment: Event better would be to just `Add-Type $SQLiteDll`, and go from there. `Assembly.Load()` is not the preferred way to import libraries.